Shrink frame when blank lines are removed (or expand frame based o numer of lines) iReport 5.6.0
I have six lines of two textfields inside a frame plus a line of totals above them. I used frames so when one textfield expands the other moves vertically with it. I also have a round rectangle that serves as a border for the whole subreport. Each ot these six lines is optional (only one minimum)
When one line doesn't have values i want to remove it; and have the subreport, band, and round rectangle to match the size needed, without leaving blanck space below or between lines.
I tried to have the round rectangle encompass all the lines and have it shrink when lines are removed, but it doesn't seem to be possible. I then tried to make it the minimum size (1 line + total line) and have it expand if there are more lines. I tried the same but putting everything inside another frame and/or reducing the band size, but then i get "Element reaches outside frame height".
I tried to make a simple example with the hope it shoes what im trying to do
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="example" pageWidth="565" pageHeight="800" columnWidth="565" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="f5e0f571-54c8-4c62-adac-79d2e8b703f6">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.7715610000000104"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="355" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="10" y="10" width="545" height="335" uuid="8799f93a-3d87-410e-b254-d1b50c3f38aa"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                    <reportElement key="textField" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="10" width="465" height="15" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#495057" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="f1493dd1-1046-4270-ba3a-0b7d02b797f3"/>
                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="2">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["This is the total"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                    <reportElement key="textField" mode="Opaque" x="495" y="10" width="50" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#495057" backcolor="#F8F9FA" uuid="41fac4f7-bd77-40e8-87b4-9d4cd816e601"/>
                    <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="2">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="9" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[15]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="40" width="545" height="35" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="e052c6e5-2ab1-4061-98d6-01debf0f2e0b"/>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement key="textField" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Transparent" x="10" y="0" width="440" height="35" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#495057" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="0cdbf741-fb5f-4a27-8386-04b706640ba1"/>
                        <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="2">
                            <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["This is the first line"]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement key="textField" positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="480" y="0" width="50" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#495057" backcolor="#F8F9FA" uuid="bc6699ef-08e1-4352-a325-23e6f46ebe7f"/>
                        <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="2">
                            <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="9" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[5]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="90" width="545" height="35" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="9c9d0e70-dbce-4e19-8c11-34584b390ccc"/>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement key="textField" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Transparent" x="10" y="0" width="440" height="35" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#495057" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="669a1271-e063-4346-b6d1-d7ea867acac7"/>
                        <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="2">
                            <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                        </textElement>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement key="textField" positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="480" y="0" width="50" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#495057" backcolor="#F8F9FA" uuid="96635a9a-1216-4b3f-a5b2-f091017f50e3"/>
                        <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="2">
                            <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="9" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                        </textElement>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="140" width="545" height="35" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="b7965fb7-649b-4e8f-b256-d94b57919c4e"/>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement key="textField" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Transparent" x="10" y="0" width="440" height="35" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#495057" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="d60699cf-faff-4fbf-9e6b-cc8fcf4fc6f0"/>
                        <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="2">
                            <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["This is the third line \n a \n a \n a \n a \n a \n a \n a \n a \n a "]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement key="textField" mode="Opaque" x="480" y="0" width="50" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#495057" backcolor="#F8F9FA" uuid="00799e93-b0cb-4e79-91c7-a12d09d95b66"/>
                        <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="2">
                            <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="9" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[5]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="190" width="545" height="35" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="d31483b3-1d4b-48fb-ac6b-8d8dfadfcd0f"/>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement key="textField" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Transparent" x="10" y="0" width="440" height="35" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#495057" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="262290a3-7a88-455c-9781-09a3d67b065f"/>
                        <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="2">
                            <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["This is the fourth line"]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement key="textField" mode="Opaque" x="480" y="0" width="50" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#495057" backcolor="#F8F9FA" uuid="9a217221-9cd8-42b3-9b48-8eccd480947a"/>
                        <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="2">
                            <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="9" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[5]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="240" width="545" height="35" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="23fe11c0-ca05-4d80-a176-4c498f73a20e"/>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement key="textField" mode="Transparent" x="10" y="0" width="440" height="35" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#495057" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="001bae39-071b-4a9c-9098-5cf8ba765365"/>
                        <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="2">
                            <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                        </textElement>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement key="textField" mode="Opaque" x="480" y="0" width="50" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#495057" backcolor="#F8F9FA" uuid="84b627bd-e6e4-42eb-b19e-c095b5951613"/>
                        <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="2">
                            <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="9" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                        </textElement>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="290" width="545" height="35" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="7cec6779-75b2-4621-8a56-91de3dbbbeb4"/>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement key="textField" mode="Transparent" x="10" y="0" width="440" height="35" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#495057" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="e9a0865b-4765-47b1-ad5c-6280bd0fee61"/>
                        <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="2">
                            <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                        </textElement>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement key="textField" mode="Opaque" x="480" y="0" width="50" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#495057" backcolor="#F8F9FA" uuid="37fe79a3-b784-44e1-8cfb-cb8787ffaa09"/>
                        <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="5" bottomPadding="4" rightPadding="2">
                            <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="9" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                        </textElement>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
                <rectangle radius="3">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="545" height="335" uuid="20126a30-f662-4d1f-9497-fe7170a93dd6"/>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 125, 0.078431375)"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </rectangle>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>


Here i have data in the first, third and fourth line; the third being long and overflowing
and i want it to look like this
but i am at a loss about how to do it
Thank you
